# How to use tFlowToIterate component parallel

Tags: mysql, talend

How to use tFlowToIterate component to parallel do mulitple queries foreach iterate
and then join de queries together with tmap.

do anyone know how to solve this problem with Talend Open Studio??

i have tried several options see Printscreens
Its not to possible to connect the tFlowToIterate component to the Mysql_Input component if the Mysql_input component is connect as a Lookup.

Example 1:
[image: Example_1]

Example 2:
[image]

EDITED:
All DiscountLevel_x are different queries and different tables

1. output of the First sigIds(Mysql_input Component) are 5 Rows (GroupIds, Percentage) which will be Iterate.
2. Every iterate will pass the GroupId and Percentage to the DiscountLevel_x Mysql_input component (Parallel to 4 queries)
3. After all 4 queries has run (discount calculation has finished) it must be join(tMap) to save it in another table.

Data:

[image]

DiscountLevel_1:

[image]

DiscountLevel_2

[image]

DiscountLevel_3

etc....

DiscountLevel_4

etc...

tMap output Schema will be look like this:
[image]

the output will be saved for each GroupId

Comment: what do you want to achive...as with tmap first looksup will be loaded and then main table/sql...what is that you are trying to here as end result..

Comment: What are you passing to your tMySqlInput components? Is it just some id field?

Comment: I am passing a Id and a Percentage Field

Comment: @garpitmzn raises a good point: your lookups need to be loaded before the main job flow typically. You might be better rephrasing your question more broadly to state what you're trying to achieve and asking how to do that specifically.

Comment: I have updated my question with what i want to achieve. i hope its clear

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive an old thread, but I bumped into the exact same problem.

Solved it by using:

tFlowToIterate--Iterate-->tSleep--OnComponentOk-->tMySQLInput--main-->tMap